# Skip a step in Setup Project

Tags: c#, setup-project, custom-action

I am using Setup Project of Visual Studio 2010 to create setup for my application. I have three custom forms in it, first custom form will have two check boxes, checkbox A and checkbox B and other two custom forms will text fields to get information from the user,

if a user checks checkbox A then Textbox A form will show and skip the Textbox B and

if user checks checkbox B then it will skip Textbox A form and show only Textbox B form and

if user checks both check boxes then Textbox A form will show and then Textbox B will show.

Is the above situation is possible in Setup Project?

If yes then How?
 or 
else I have to use some other installer?

Please suggest...!

[image]

Comment: This is explained in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9x23561f(v=vs.100).aspx) for VS2010 setup projects.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in a setup project because there is no way to alter the display of those dialogs based on conditions or settings from previous dialogs. You'd need another tool to do that kind of thing during the install.

If it's related to configuring the app (and not strictly the install) then it's sometimes better (as well as easier) to run the configuration step when your app first runs. This is very easy to test and debug and you get a more modern looking UI than the installer provides, and it lets the user change the configuration without re-installing.